# Use an int declared in class in a switch statement in one of the methods in the class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting the error `"this cannot be used in a constant expression."` What I am trying to do should be quite a simple task. All I would like to be able to do is use a variable declared in a class in a switch statement that is within a method in the class. For example:

In the class

```
private:
int someValue;
```

In the class constructor

```
Classname::ClassName(){
   someValue = 1;

}
```

In the method

```
ClassName::someMethod(){
   int command = getCommandNumber();

   switch (command){
      case someValue:
        doSomeStuff();
        break;  


   }


}
```

In the method if I replace `someValue` with just the number `1`, everything works fine; however, if I use `someValue`, it won't compile, and it gives me the error stated above. How can I fix this?

Comment: The case labels in a `switch` expression requires constants known at compile time. `someValue` must either be something of the same order with `constexpr`; or some prvalue constant, or an *enum*. If you must use a runtime criteria, use *if-else* ladder

Comment: @Whiz Make this an answer?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, Thanks. done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` *labels* in a *switch-statement* requires constants known at compile time. `someValue` must either be something of the same order with `constexpr`; or some `prvalue` constant; or an `enum` or `enum class` . If you must use a runtime criteria, use an *if-else* ladder.

```
ClassName::someMethod(){
   int command = getCommandNumber();
        if(command == someValue)
            doSomeStuff();
        else if(command == ...)
            ....
   }
}
```